# easiest way to delete backslash from file name

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I have a list of files similar to the following and I need to delete the backslash:

```
\jskadn.txt
\jsandkjasn5.txt
```

I tried running the following command, but it doesn't work :

```
rename " \\*.txt" "*.txt"
```

Comment: What version / implementation of `rename` are you trying to use here?

Comment: @steeldriver v 1.13

Comment: @PythonUser I was more interested in whether it's the perl based file-rename or the util-linux implementation - the version number suggests the former but the syntax of your attempt suggests the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With the Perl-based file-rename:

  ```
  $ rename --version
  /usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.10
  ```

  then using a `sed`-style regular expression `s/pattern/replacement/`:

  ```
  $ rename -vn 's/\\//' \\*.txt
  rename(\jsandkjasn5.txt, jsandkjasn5.txt)
  rename(\jskadn.txt, jskadn.txt)
  ```
- With `util-linux` rename (which takes simple `pattern` `replacement` arguments):

  ```
  $ rename.ul --version
  rename.ul from util-linux 2.34
  ```

  then:

  ```
  $ rename.ul -vn '\' '' \\*.txt
  `\jsandkjasn5.txt' -> `jsandkjasn5.txt'
  `\jskadn.txt' -> `jskadn.txt'
  ```

  (you can use `\\` in place of `'\'` if you prefer). Remove the `-n` (no-op) switch once you are convinced they are doing the right thing.
- For completeness, using `mmv`:

  ```
  $ mmv -n '\\*' '#1'
  \jsandkjasn5.txt -> jsandkjasn5.txt
  \jskadn.txt -> jskadn.txt
  ```
- Or a simple shell loop:

  ```
  $ for f in \\*.txt; do echo mv "$f" "${f#?}"; done
  mv \jsandkjasn5.txt jsandkjasn5.txt
  mv \jskadn.txt jskadn.txt
  ```

  (remove the `echo` in this case).